# Boost: Unknown type name 'reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I am trying to run an old project in Xcode, which is written in C++, but I get several errors with boost library.

The first was [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8092) issue, but the second comment provided a nice workaround and it worked.

Then I did a clean build again and now I am getting the error, which is in the title, namely:

```
Unknown type name 'reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper'
```

I can't find any solution for this issue. Anybody has any suggestions?

I am using:

- Mac OSX 10.10
- Xcode Version 6.1 (in the project C++ language dialect and C++ standard library are set to Compiler default)
- Boost 1.56

Comment: That's not a lot of information to go on... The type appears to be defined in `boost/optional.hpp`. Without seeing some source, or more of the error, it's impossible to help you any more than that.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cannot share the source, because it is private and also really big, but I managed to overcome it with a temporary workaround. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pass through this error, with a temporary workaround. It is not the nicest solution probably, but works...

What I did is just simply commented out these lines from boost/optional.hpp:

```
// reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper operator *() && { return boost::move(this->get()) ; }

// reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper value() &&
//   { 
//     if (this->is_initialized())
//       return boost::move(this->get()) ;
//     else
//       throw_exception(bad_optional_access());
//   }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is already an accepted answer but it bypasses the issue, doesn't really fix it so I thought I would respond with a more up-to-date answer for those searching.

In more recent versions of Boost, there are preprocessor definitions that you can pass to your app that will disable certain C++11 features. For the particular error in this post, passing this to the compiler fixes the issue (GCC here):

```
-DBOOST_NO_CXX11_REF_QUALIFIERS
```

There is a nice long list on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406974/disable-exception-working-for-boostsmart-ptr-but-not-for-boostproperty-tree) of all the C++11-related Boost preprocessor definitions that can be set.