# Disable exception working for boost::smart_ptr but not for boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-propertytree, boost-smart-ptr

I'm using boost 1.57.
I need to disable exception support in my not widely-used proprietary compiler.
When I needed to use `boost::smart_ptr`, the following steps worked like a charm:

1. Disabled C++11 support using the following `user.hpp` file (compiling with `-DBOOST_USER_CONFIG="<user.hpp>"`):

   ```
   #define BOOST_HAS_NRVO
   #define BOOST_NO_COMPLETE_VALUE_INITIALIZATION
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_DECLARATIONS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_MULTIDECLARATIONS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR16_T
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR32_T
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE_N3276
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_EXPLICIT_CONVERSION_OPERATORS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_FINAL
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_ARGS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_LAMBDAS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_LOCAL_CLASS_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RANGE_BASED_FOR
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RAW_LITERALS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_REF_QUALIFIERS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_STATIC_ASSERT
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIASES
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_UNICODE_LITERALS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_UNIFIED_INITIALIZATION_SYNTAX
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_USER_DEFINED_LITERALS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_MACROS
   #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES
   #define BOOST_NO_SFINAE_EXPR
   #define BOOST_NO_TWO_PHASE_NAME_LOOKUP
   ```
2. Informs boost libraries not to use exceptions: `-DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DBOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE`
3. Resulting in the following compilation line: `MyCOMPILER -DBOOST_USER_CONFIG="<user.hpp>" -DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DBOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE -c Foo.cpp -o Foo.o`

Then the following piece of code successfully compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp>

namespace boost {
    void throw_exception(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Fake exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::exit(255);
    }
}

class Foo {
  private:
    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
  public:
    bool bar(const std::string file_name) {
      ptr = boost::make_shared<int>();
      return true;
    }
};
```

But when I've tried to use the above method with the following source code, the compilation goes wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace boost {
    void throw_exception(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Fake exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::exit(255);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public:
      bool bar(const std::string file_name) {   
        boost::property_tree::ptree prop_tree;
        boost::property_tree::read_ini(file_name, prop_tree);

        return !prop_tree.empty();
      }
};
```

Resulting the following errors for instance:

```
"boost\boost/optional/optional.hpp", line 1047: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::bad_optional_access" to "const std::exception" exists
            throw_exception(bad_optional_access());
                            ^
"boost\boost/optional/optional.hpp", line 1055: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::bad_optional_access" to "const std::exception" exists
            throw_exception(bad_optional_access());
                            ^
"boost\boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp", line 138: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::runtime_error" to "const std::exception" exists
          boost::throw_exception(std::runtime_error("Type name demangling failed"));
                                 ^
"boost\boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp", line 168: Error:  #540: support for exception handling is disabled; use --exceptions to enable
          try {
          ^
```

Finally the question:

Why in the first case all works OK, but not in the second?
How can I get `boost::property_tree` to compile properly without exception support? Is this even possible?